# Cannot access the docker path in docker toolbox /usr/share/nginx/html

Tags: docker, nginx

I am using a Docker Toolbox on Windows 8 and trying to run angular application from nginx in Docker.I have `nginx` runnning on my system and rendering the default nginx page,but I want to render my application.I give the below command using this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-nginx-in-a-docker-container-on-ubuntu-14-04) as reference.

```
docker run --name docker-nginx -p 80:80 -d -v ~/docker-nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

I am not able to figure out where `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory is present on my docker toolbox.I can traverse `/usr/share` but there is no nginx directory present.Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me without making any changes.

Just make sure that ~/docker-nginx/html is using your home folder.

For me it resulted in

```
C:\Users\Dominic\docker-nginx\html
```

I double checked the path inside the container and it's working.

Comment: Thanks for responding.I am looking for path in the nginx server on  /usr/share/nginx/html

Comment: Working just fine. It even displayed the index.html file in that folder.